# Jenkins cannot reach nodes after upgrade

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, upgrade

I just upgraded Jenkins from 2.39 to 2.57. After the upgrade, Jenkins can no longer communicate with my SSH build nodes. I get the following error:

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Slave JVM has not reported exit code. Is it still running?
[04/28/17 01:29:32] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[04/28/17 01:29:32] [SSH] Connection closed.
ERROR: Connection terminated
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2335)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:73)
```

Based on Googling 'Slave JVM has not reported exit code.' it seems like a Java version mismatch ([JENKINS-30561](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30561), [JENKINS-29120](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29120)), but I can confirm that my build nodes are using Java 1.7:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone have ideas what could be causing this? More info can be provided on request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out via this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414585/unable-to-start-jenkins-slave) which pointed me to [JENKINS-27624](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27624) which indicates that Java 8 is now required.

Update: I upgraded Java on all my nodes this morning and they are up and working.